# find what Server.CreateObject is trying to make

Tags: asp-classic

I am porting a windows 2003 app to windows 2008r2.  It is a classic ASP app.  On line 32 of awebpage.asp the following code is used:

```
Server.CreateObject("some.custom.name.here")
```

When running the page in a browser I get the following error

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/awebpage.asp, line 32

800401f3
```

Anyone know how I should go about finding where this "some.custom.name.here" object is on the old server so I can move it over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for this object name in **RegEdit**, under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Once you find it you get its ProgID / CLSID (a long GUID number), find that long number in RegEdit and you'll get to a key with this number. Under that key there will be another key (probably `InprocServer32`) which contains the requested .dll / .exe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found the object, but it does not tell me where it is located on the drive.  Any idea how I get that info?

Comment: It should. One of the child keys/values should show the full file path of the DLL.

Comment: There is a CLSID field on the one child value.  It has a big number.

Comment: but I was able to search for that number and found the source code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ofer: Please edit this answer to include a more detailed description of how to go from the ProgID entry in HKEY_CLASS_ROOT to the InProc server entry for the CLSID.